# Leaflet.js file runs in Safari but not Firefox, Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, leaflet

I am trying to create a mapping application that uses Leaflet.js to overlay GeoJson files on top of an OpenStreetMap file.  The whole file is set out below and the GeoJson files are located on my GitHub page at https://github.com/ELamar/zoning

I can get the file to run in Safari, but can't get the file to run in Firefox, Chrome or IE.  Nothing in the web inspectors for those browsers indicates any kind of error.  The JSON files are very large (one is 9 MB and another about 6 MB), and I have nested the callbacks that read in the files.  Could the issue be that is too much data to try to run in those browsers?  If so, why would it run in Safari?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<style>
svg {
  position: relative;
}
</style>

<!--This file illustrates a map of Leon County Florida, complete with 
2010 census block heatmap of population-->
<h1>This is a Draft Concept for a Collaborative Zoning Map.</h1>

<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 600px"></div>
    <div id="detail" style="width: 30%; height: 600px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!--<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./leaflet.js"></script>
<!--<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>--    >
<script src="./jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!--<script src="./flare4.json"></script>-->
<!--<script src="./flare5.json"></script>-->
<script>
var map;
var ajaxRequest;
var plotlist;
var plotlayers=[];

function initmap() {
    // set up the map
    map = new L.Map('map');

    // create the tile layer with correct attribution
    //var osmUrl='http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=13/30.4467/-84.3087';
    //var osmUrl='http://osm.org/go/ZGUQ8RJ';
    var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osmAttrib='Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>     contributors';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib});       

    // start the map in Tallahassee Florida
    //map.setView(new L.LatLng(30.4467,-84.3087),11);  //sets view to Leon County
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(30.4606,-84.2780),15);  //sets view to MidTown Tallahassee
    map.addLayer(osm);


  }

 initmap();
 var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
 var osmAttrib='Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>     contributors';
 var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib});  
 var baselayers = {"baselayer":osm};    

 function onEachFeature(feature, layer){

            var med_age = feature.properties.median_age;
            var str = med_age.toString();
            layer.bindPopup("Media age: " + str);
            // if (med_age > 0){
//              layer.setStyle({fillOpacity:0.7});
//              }
//          else{
//              layer.setStyle({fillOpacity:0});
//              }
// [0,15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85])
            if (med_age > 85){layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#03f",fillOpacity:0.9});}
            else if (med_age > 75)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#08306B",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (med_age > 65)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#08519C",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (med_age > 55)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#2171B5",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (med_age > 45)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#4292C6",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (med_age > 35){layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#6BAED6",fillOpacity:0.5});}
        else if (med_age > 25){layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#9ECAE1",fillOpacity:0.5});}
        else if (med_age > 15){layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#C6DBEf",fillOpacity:0.5});}
        else if (med_age > 0){layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#DEEBF7",fillOpacity:0.5});}
        else {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#f7fbff", fillOpacity:0});}

         layer.on("mouseover", function (e) {
              //var txt = layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.median_age);
             // var text = layer.bindPopup(str);
              var box = document.getElementById('detail');
              //layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.median_age);
              box.innerHTML = "Median age: " + str;
          });
          layer.on("mouseout", function (e) { 
          box = document.getElementById('detail');
          box.innerHTML="";
          }); 


        }


function onEachFeature_zone(feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup("ID: " + feature.id + "<br>" + "Zoning: " +     feature.properties.zoning);
    }

function onEachFeature_active(feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup("ID: " + feature.id + "<br>" + "Zoning: " + feature.properties.zoning     + "<br>" + "<a href='https://github.com/ELamar/Superior-Planning-PUD'>Comment Here</a>");
    }

function onEachFeature_pop(feature, layer){

            var pop = feature.properties.population;
            var str = pop.toString();
            layer.bindPopup("Population: " + str);
            // if (med_age > 0){
//              layer.setStyle({fillOpacity:0.7});
//              }
//          else{
//              layer.setStyle({fillOpacity:0});
//              }
// [0,15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85])
//[0,11,51,101,251,501,901,1201,1500])
            if (pop > 1500){layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#03f",fillOpacity:0.9});}
            else if (pop > 1201)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#08306B",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (pop > 901)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#08519C",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (pop > 501)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#2171B5",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (pop > 251)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#4292C6",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (pop > 101)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#6BAED6",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (pop > 51)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#9ECAE1",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (pop > 11)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#C6DBEf",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else if (pop > 0)    {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#DEEBF7",fillOpacity:0.5});}
            else {layer.setStyle({fillColor:"#f7fbff", fillOpacity:0});}

             layer.on("mouseover", function (e) {
                  //var txt = layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.median_age);
                 // var text = layer.bindPopup(str);
                  var box = document.getElementById('detail');
                  //layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.median_age);
                  box.innerHTML = "Population: " + str;
              });
              layer.on("mouseout", function (e) { 
              box = document.getElementById('detail');
              box.innerHTML="";
              }); 


            }


$.getJSON("./flare5.json", function(json){
var geojson_d3 = L.geoJson(json,{
    weight:0,onEachFeature:onEachFeature
    })
var geojson3_d3 = L.geoJson(json,{
    weight:0, onEachFeature:onEachFeature_pop
    })
    var overlays = {"median_age" : geojson_d3, "population":geojson3_d3};

    $.getJSON("./flare4.json", function(data){
        var geojson2_d3 = L.geoJson(data,{fill:true, weight:1.5, color:'#800026',     fillOpacity: 0, onEachFeature:onEachFeature_zone})  //function(feature,layer)    {layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.zoning)}})

        overlays["zoning"] =  geojson2_d3;

        $.getJSON("./flare7.json", function(active){
            var geojson2_d4 = L.geoJson(active,{fill:true, weight:1.5, color:'#800026',     fillOpacity: 0, onEachFeature:onEachFeature_active})  //function(feature,layer)    {layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.zoning)}})
            overlays["active zoning"] =  geojson2_d4;
            var control = L.control.layers(baselayers, overlays).addTo(map)}
            );
        }
    );
      }
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you might add some console.log statements in the nested getJSON calls to see how far the code is getting...and yeah, those files are pretty big, the problem could also be in the rendering (attempts at rendering too many features will crash most browsers)

Comment: Thanks.  Will try adding console.log statements as you suggest.  Hopefully, that will shed some light on things.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.  A friend suggest that I look again at the data retrieval.  I ran snippets of the json code through [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) and noticed that the json files did not validate because I had terminated each of them with a semicolon.  Apparently Safari will parse json files just fine this way, but other browsers will not.  Once I deleted the semicolon, the files worked fine in IE and Firefox.  I have not tested it yet in Chrome, but I suspect it will work now.

Thanks all for the suggestions.